# Why did Vader continue to serve Palpatine?

Tags: star-wars

I'm not sure I understand why Vader continued to serve Palpatine after Padme died.  What did Palpatine have to offer him?

Anakin is an angry individual, but not necessarily an evil one.  "There's good in him still, I can feel it," as Luke said to Obi-Wan in Ep 6.

Was it the Dark Side itself that compelled him to serve Palpatine?  Did he feel that his disfigurements would mean he would not be able to function in any other role?   Why *exactly* did Vader stick around?